# Multiplying strings as polynomials

Tags: functions, polynomials, binary, bit-strings

Interdisciplinary Question:

[image]

How to approach the question and arrive at the solution?

Comment: Source of this question, please?

Comment: A Book, but solution for that particular book is not provided

Comment: Which book, please?

Comment: Mathematics Higher Level - Nigel Buckle, et.al

Comment: Seems like a strange question for a textbook, especially if there's nothing in the book explaining how to do polynomial operations in binary. I'd suggest calculating $A^2,A^3,A^4$ to see whether any pattern emerges.